# Flutter app not running with android studio 3.5

Tags: flutter

- What went wrong:
  Could not update C:\Users\QUADPRO 3.gradle\caches\4.10.2\file-changes\last-build.bin

  > C:\Users\QUADPRO 3.gradle\caches\4.10.2\file-changes\last-build.bin (Access is denied)

Answer (score 1):

Goto File -> Invalidate caches / Restart

Shutdown Android Studio

Rename/remove .gradle folder in the user home directory

Restart Android Studio (It will download gradle metadata and data)

Gradle build succeed

Rebuild project.

Comment: saved  my day, Thanks

Comment: @neena enjoy your code, don't forget to check answer.